# Calculating total minutes of an employee

Tags: sql-server

```
select top 10 DATEDIFF(minute,[clock_in],[clock_out]) AS TOTAL_MINS
```

Getting below error

> The datediff function resulted in an overflow. The number of dateparts
>   separating two date/time instances is too large. Try to use datediff
>   with a less precise datepart.

Comment: Try running the same query using `day` instead of `minute`.  Sounds like you have an entry or two that are much farther apart than expected.

Comment: The difference between two time instances is too large, as said. If possible, reduce the precision. Try to do `DATEDIFF(hour,[clock_in],[clock_out])` to get rid of the error, and use `* 60` to convert the result to minute.

Comment: I think the real problem is in your data. no employee will work for 96198 DAYS at a stretch (time between clock_in and clock_out, where the number of minutes gets too large). 

OK, except for Professional SQL-Server developers ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Even `SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '1753-01-01', '5836-01-01')` do not cause the int overflow and much longer than human life, review your storage of employee `clock_in` and `clock_out` data.

Answer (score 0):

`DATEDIFF`'s return value is an integer. If the return value is not in range of an integer then you will get an error. Try the below query to get minutes.

```
    select TOTAL_HRS*60 + DATEDIFF(mi,DATEADD(hh,CAST(TOTAL_HRS as int),Clock_in),clock_out) as Total_Mins
from

    (select top 10 DATEDIFF(hh,[clock_in],[clock_out]) AS TOTAL_HRS,clock_in,clock_out
    from tab) t
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query. May be its helps you.

```
select top 10 DATEDIFF(HOUR,[clock_in],[clock_out])*60 AS TOTAL_MINS
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my test I found below:

`SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE,'0001-01-01 00:00:00.000','4083-12-31 00:00:00.000') AS TOTAL_MINS`

**TOTAL_MINS**

2147124540

`SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE,'0001-01-01 00:00:00.000','4084-05-19 00:00:00.000') AS TOTAL_MINS`

**TOTAL_MINS**

Msg 535, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
The datediff function resulted in an overflow. The number of dateparts separating two date/time instances is too large. Try to use datediff with a less precise datepart.

*So it clearly indicates that your datetime data value contains some invalid data.*